# C for loop failing

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

So I'm new in C language and I'm trying to do a histogram with the length of the words the user typed, I have a solution but my second for loop always fail, I code like 5 for loop and every of them just stop after the second or third iteration, Am I missing something please help. Here's my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int i,x,c,r,size;
    int wa[10];
    size=0;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        wa[i]=0;
    }
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF){
        switch(c){
            case' ':{
                wa[size]++;
                size=0;
                break;}
            case'\n':{
                wa[size]++;
                size=0;
                break;}
            case'\t':{
                wa[size]++;
                size=0;
                break;}
            default:{
                size++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    for(r=0;r<=10;++r){
        printf("%d",r);
        for(x=0;x<wa[r];x++){
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why is `wa[4]` special? I guess that `default` is executed when letters are found but still it's unclear.

Comment: aggred with  @coderredoc why wa[4] is special . Your default case only increment size not value of w[].

Comment: i tried compiling this code and running the program and i'm infinitely stuck in the while loop.

Comment: oh wa[4] is just for test that the rest of the code is working ... to finish the White loop press ctrl+c in your console .

Comment: Please show a sample input and output, pointing out why you think the output is incorrect.

Comment: Not related to the second for loop, but `for(r=0;r<=10;++r)` is wrong. `wa` only holds 10 items.

Comment: You should start up your debugger and see what values your variables get in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- first, for testing purposes when running from Linux commandline <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> emulates EOF

  - second, your for loop iterates between ( 0 -10 inclusive ), your `wa` array index however is ranging from (0 - 9 inclusive ) which means:

    for(x=0;x

  call may cause SEGFAULT

  - third, you are missing a simple case where the input is just one word with no whitespace after, something like

  > abcdEOF

  - fourth, following the second paragraph when entering valus to the array your indexing is wrong
  - as far as the assumption that the longest words is 10char long thats fine but you must verify that the `size` never exceeds the value of 9 or if you will correct the `wa` update then 10 exceeding this value will cause segfault due to updating un-allocated index in the array

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The first for loop will start from 1, and in the second for loop replace wa[4] with wa[r].

Your code also assume that no word will be longer than 10 char.

Comment: yes my mistake I used wa[4] to test if the rest of the code is working,  the problem is that every loop I write after the while dont finish.

Comment: @JaredJosafhatHZ Do you have any indication that the loop even starts?